# Unity Editor - Is there a way to easily add object and function references to a custom inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Like for example what Unity does on the Button component (the events).

[image: Button events]

I want to add a reference to an object, and then a reference to a public function on that object.

Comment: Inserting items to main menu: [EditorWindow](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html)

Comment: Which part do you want elaborated? The visualization(the drop down menu), the localization ( the binding of objects) or the obtaining of the values (the public values).?

Comment: Well, everything you just mentioned would be nice. I think the title of this question makes it rather clear about what I want to achieve.
I don't want to sound ungrateful, but I have no idea how to explain it in better terms.
I want the user to select a game object, then select a function residing in one of the components attached to that game object then I want to invoke that function and take the return value and then do something with it.

Answer (score -2):

You can get a high level of understanding of how unity does it by using a dll decompiller, [ILSpy.net](http://ILSpy.net), and then decompile the UnityEngine.dll and UnityEditor.dll and look at the Events class because it is fairly complex.

Comment: _[**Accordingly, you agree not to disassemble, decompile or reverse engineer the Software, in whole or in part, or permit or authorize a third party to do so, except to the extent such activities are expressly permitted by law notwithstanding this prohibition.**](https://unity3d.com/legal/eula)_